# Angular, array is copied too late

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, cordova

I have a callback function that it is used with the data from the server response.
In the function i m trying to populate an array with the data result. 
The array that i m populating is defined in a service from a different module that is inserted in my main application module. I m using this method to have access to this array in all my controllers, some sort of global known array.

```js
angular.module('HighLowTodayApp.services', [])
    .factory('HLTglobalData',['$http',function($http){
       globalData.currentDomainsList = {};
      return {
            currentDomainsList : globalData.currentDomainsList
      }
    });
```

The callback function that populates the array looks like this:

```js
$scope.getDomainsStatisticsSuccess = function(data){

  HLTglobalData.currentDomainsList = data.slice();

  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(HLTglobalData.currentDomainsList));

  //go to showDomainsList page
  $location.path("/showDomainsList");
  
};
```

The problem is that the init() function of the controller from "/showDomainsList" path it is triggered earlier then the populating of the HLTglobalData.currentDomainsList.

I have a console.log(JSON.stringify(HLTglobalData.currentDomainsList)) in the mentioned init() function and that one it is shown in the console with an empty object {} and also it is shown earlier then the two console.log's from the 
getDomainsStatisticsSuccess function.

Somehow the location it is changed prior to finishing copying the array.
I'vd used this method in all my project and this is the only place it acts like this.

I forgot to mention that the angular application it is running in a Cordova project, but i think this should not be an issue.

Any idea ? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the best way work with async stuff is Promise. for example:

```

```
function myService($q){
 var def = $q.defer
 $http().then((data) => def.resolve(data))
 return def
}

function myCtrl($location) {
 myService.then(() => $location.path('/somewhere'))
}
```

```

Comment: I solved my problem - it was due to an error of mine - i forgot to comment a call to $location.path("/showDomainsList"); a few lines above the ajax request. So my code did the changing of the path and then was making the ajax request with setting the success, and the init of the controller was called only at the first call to changing the path.
 
Anyway thanks a lot. With this ocasion i learned something new - deferred . I found my bug only after testing with $q. Thanks !